# How can I make a simple tkinter input box that creates a file with user input as name using os?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make tkinter input box to create a file using os' "touch". Code attached down below. Instead of creating the named file, it gives me the following message:
`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects`

I have tried the os.system lines with # before them, but it did nothing. Could anyone please tell me what I need to fix to get this working?

My operating system is MacOS if that is important.

````
from tkinter import *
import os

os.system("clear")

root = tk.Tk()

def createFile():
    #os.system("cd ~")
    os.system("touch" + e1)
    #os.system.pack()
    
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()

button1 = Button(root, text="Create File", command=createFile)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are trying to concatenate *'touch'* string with an Entry object. You should get the entry text first by using `.get` method. Also, there should be a space after `touch` probably, i.e. `touch` . And in general, why do you need `system`? For example, in Windows the `touch` command would fail. There is `open` function in Python for creating and reading files. Also I would recommend not to use * in import. A linter (for example pylint) would complain about this approach.

The code I suggest is:

```py
import tkinter as tk 
import os 
 
os.system("clear") 
root = tk.Tk() 
 
def createFile(): 
    # os.system("touch " + e1.get()) 
    # I suggest this: 
    file = open(e1.get(), 'w') 
    file.close() 
 
e1 = tk.Entry(root) 
e1.pack() 
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Create File", command=createFile) 
button1.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about the .get thing, because I usually just combine the variable with text and it worked without .get until now